# Ubuntu Installation hangs on 1.5yr old PC?

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu yesterday, burned it to a cd and tried to install it on my pc using a clean drive(new), but Ubuntus label and progress bar just stays on the screen, nothing loads up I've let it run for 2 hours, but no progress.

The drive is only a 120GB one, pre-formated with ext3 set as primary.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! We need more information to assist you Martin, please tell us your machine specifications (Ram, processor, etc...)!

Comment: Also, what version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: RAM is 2GB ,processor AMD not sure the model,but its 1 1/2 years old

Comment: Ubuntu version 12.04

Comment: I've edited your title and summary a bit to make it a bit clearer to other AskUbuntu users what the problem is, hope that helps :)

Comment: Is this during the actual install process?

Comment: yes,its during install

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest that there's something awry somewhere, check the download and burn.

You shouldn't have any trouble installing it to a 'newish' machine

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck